# Accessing plane track using Python API

Tags: python, tracking

I'm new to Blender and the Python language and I'm trying to extract the coordinates of the corners of a plane track from all the frames of a clip. I'm having trouble even accessing(?) the plane track object/variable. I hover over the text field containing the name of the plane track and it says

```
...
bpy.data.movieclips["1340wbdc0000.jpeg"].tracking.plane_tracks["pt"].name
```

I type that line into the console, but then I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "pt" not found'
```

However, if I enter

```
D.movieclips["1340wbdc0000.jpeg"].tracking.plane_tracks.active
```

The console "responds" with

```
bpy.data.movieclips['1340wbdc0000.jpeg'].tracking.plane_tracks["pt"]
```

This is really making me very confused and frustrated. What am I doing wrong? Could this be a bug since plane tracking is a new feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me in 2.69:

```
>>> bpy.data.movieclips[0].tracking.plane_tracks.active.markers[0].corners[0][:]
#(0.12633077800273895, 0.4383348524570465)
```

`plane_tracks.active` gives me the correct name, even if I rename it in the right sidebar of the movieclip editor. You could try `plane_tracks["Plane Track"]` or `plane_tracks[0]` instead.

Do should deselect all in the movieclip editor and re-select the tracking plane and see if `plane_track.active` changes to the correct name.

```
clip = bpy.data.movieclips["1100wbdc0000.jpeg"]
print("\nMovie Clip %s" % clip.name)

for i, ob in enumerate(clip.tracking.objects):
    print("\n\tTracking Object %s" % ob.name)

    for j, pt in enumerate(ob.plane_tracks):
        print("\t\tPlane Track %i" % j)

        for k, marker in enumerate(pt.markers):
            print("\t\t\tMarker %i" % k)

            for l, corner in enumerate(marker.corners):
                print("\t\t\t\tCorner %i = %f / %f" % (l, corner[0], corner[1]))
```

Comment: Yes, `plane_tracks.active` does give me the correct name. However if no plane track is selected, using `plane_tracks["Plane Track"]` or `plane_tracks[0]` gives me an error. I was hoping to write a script to automate the process since I have around 60 plane tracks to extract.

Comment: Of course it gives an error if there's no active plane track. If you need to access all plane tracks, why not loop over all of them? There's no need to make them / one active. `for pt in Clip.tracking.plane_tracks: pt.markers...`

Comment: That's my problem. I can't loop over all of them. I tried the following code:
`import bpy`
`i=0`
`clip=bpy.data.movieclips["1100wbdc0000.jpeg"]`
`print(clip.tracking.plane_tracks.active.name)`
`for track in clip.tracking.plane_tracks:`
`    print(i)`
`    i=i+1`

Comment: If a plane track is selected, `Plane Track` `0` is printed on the console. However, if no plane track is selected, it returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: There's no point in accessing `plane_tracks.active` if you wanna loop for all Plane Tracks, their markers and their Corners. See my answer above, added example code.

Comment: That code isn't working for me. Only `Movie Clip 1100wbdc0000.jpeg` is printed in the console. I'm using 2.69.0, by the way. My suspicion is that `tracking.plane_tracks` hasn't been implemented as an array, yet.

Comment: I use the same version and why would it be no array? It definately is: `type(clip.tracking.plane_tracks) #
<class 'bpy_prop_collection'>`. If only the clip name is printed, then there's no plane track for that movie clip.

Comment: Ok I get it now. The code you gave does work, but only for plane tracks created from tracks in the camera object. Other plane tracks created from trackers in other objects don't seem to be stored in the `tracking.plane_tracks` array which is why the code didn't work for me before. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: updated code to loop over all tracking objects, `tracking.plane_tracks` refers to `tracking.objects.active.plane_tracks`.